# How to find and leave only doubles in list python?

Tags: python

How to find only doubles in list? My version of the algorithm

```
import collections
a = [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5]
b = []

for x,y in collections.Counter(a).items():
    if y>1:
        b.append(x)

print(b)  # [2, 4, 5]

c = []
for item in a:
    if item in b:
        c.append(item)

print(c)  # [2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5]
```

need find result such as c

code defects:

1. three list (a,b,c), one collections (dict)
2. long code

me need leave list doubles values, example. x = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7‌​], need [2,2,2,6,6] not [2,6]

Comment: Yes that's right, as c list print(c)  # [2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5]
counts = Counter(a)
print([num for num in a if counts[num] > 1])
```

Comment: Could also use the counts as a dict `[x for x, y in counts.items() if y > 1]`

Comment: Though, if order is important then the posted solution is the best.

Comment: The OP requires duplicates to be returned in the list. Since it's a dictionary, iterating over the items will not do that.

Comment: Ah, good point as well.  Missed the duplicates in the OP's comment.

Comment: FWIW, a "functional" version of that last line is `print(list(filter(lambda num: counts[num] > 1, a)))`; in Python 2 the `list()` call can be eliminated.

Answer (score 5):

Not the most efficient way, but very concise:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,2,4,5]
b = [x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1]
print(b)
```

Comment: Yes, `list.count` has to scan the whole list every time, so this is O(n^2) compared to Karin's O(n) solution. OTOH, if `a` is very short, this _might_ be faster, since Counter isn't exactly fast even though it runs in O(n).

Comment: That's correct. Karin's solution is efficient and elegant. The kind of code that's enjoying to read.

Answer (score 1):

@Karin almost had it I think, but end result will not be a set.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5]
counts = Counter(a)
print({k for k, v in counts.items() if v >= 2})
```

EDIT: Ahh, "leave only doubles"

```
print([x for x in a if counts[x] >= 2])
```

EDIT2: Additional comment clarification by OP for values with anything with a double or more frequent.

Comment: The OP requires a list that contains the duplicates ("me need leave list values, not only unique"). The required output is `[2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5]`. It took me a bit of time to interpret :)

Comment: Also, OP is using Python 3.x! ;)

Comment: Also, the edit still will not work for the same reason. If counts is a dictionary, the keys will always be unique...therefore you will still not return the duplicates in the list.

Comment: Also, I think the OP meant duplicates instead of doubles, since OP provided this example in the comments: `x = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7‌​], need [2,2,2,6,6] not [2,6]`, where `2` is a triple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def duplicates(iterable=[1,3,4,5,5]):
    only_unique = set()
    doubles_or_more = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item in doubles_or_more:
            yield item
        else:
            if item in only_unique:
                yield item
                yield item # yield twice at this is the first time item is identified as a double
                doubles_or_more.add(item)
            else:
                only_unique.add(item)
# example/test
assert list(duplicates(iterable=[1,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,7])) == [2,2,2,6,6]
```